# what `circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })` means

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am learning `react native`. I am trying to understand the code [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/RNTester/js/PanResponderExample.js). The snippet below seems very weird to me. Can you please explain what it does?

```
circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })
```

I know about `if` statement like:

```
blabla = (if-this-is-true) ? this-should-be-used : otherwise_this
```

but don't know if the circle one is the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Flow type annotation. Flow is a static type checker for JavaScript (https://flow.org/).

`?Type` syntax means that type of variable is Maybe type, so it can be `undefined`, `null` or accept provided "Type". For example ?string would mean `string`, `null`, or `undefined`. More about his type in flow [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/).

The `(null: Type)` syntax is a type cast expression ([link](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/)). Using type cast expressions you can assert that values are certain types or cast value to certain type.

In your question `(null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void })` null will be casted to Maybe type that accepts:

- object with method `setNativeProps`, taking object as argument and returning nothing (`void` type),
- `null`,
- `undefined`

Comment: if i didn't what to use Flow, how should it be coded?

Comment: It's literally just `circle: null` if you don't include the annotation.

Answer (score 2):

`(x: y)` is how type casting is performed in flow. I.e. the value `x` is cast to type `y`.

In your case `null` is refined as

```
?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void }
```

which is a nullable object that has method `setNativeProps`. This method accepts an object and reruns nothing (`void`).

Learn more about flow at https://flow.org/.

Comment: if i didn't what to use Flow, how should it be coded?